# How to drag and drop multiple rows from source datatable to target datatable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, drag-and-drop

I want to drag multiple rows from source datatable and drop them to target datatable on a specific row.

When dropping them on target row, I want to fire an event.

I used dropListener for that, which is included in a c:foreach, but the method onDrop isn't called.

This is the droppable datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="dispoFillingAuftrag" var="data" value="#{dispoFillingPage.auftragList}" widgetVar="#{focusedTab}_auftrag" 
             rowKey="#{data.orderNr}"
             draggableColumns="true" 
             droppable="true"
             resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true" emptyMessage="#{msg['form.dispoFillingPage.noAuftragFound']}" rows="20"
             selectionMode="single" selection="#{dispoFillingPage.selectedAuftrag}" 
             filteredValue="#{dispoFillingPage.filteredAuftragList}" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="both" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
             >              


    <c:forEach var="column" items="#{dispoFillingPage.columnListAuftrag}">
        <p:column id="#{column.id}" filterStyleClass="#{column.filterStyleClass}" headerText="#{column.title}" visible="#{column.visible}" width="#{column.width}" filterBy="#{data[column.property]}" filterMatchMode="contains" styleClass="mainPageCompanyColumn">
            <f:attribute name="rtcCol" value="#{column}"/>
            <p:outputPanel id="cats1">
                <h:outputText value="#{data[column.property]}" />
            </p:outputPanel>

              <p:droppable for="cats1"
                         dropListener="#{dispoFillingPage.onDrop}"
                         tolerance="pointer"
                         activeStyleClass="slotActive"
                         datasource="dispoFillingKWG">
            </p:droppable>
        </p:column>
    </c:forEach>

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `c:forEach` into the datatable instead of [`p:columns`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml)?

Comment: I don't think drag/drop from/to datatables 'just works'. I think you need something like http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dnd/custom.xhtml